# Обрубает подключение к MySQL в проекте nestjs-telegraf и prisma

Tags: typescript, nestjs, telegraf, prisma

Есть сервер Ubuntu 20.04, проект написан на стеке: `nestjs-telegraf, telegraf, prisma ORM, typescript`

Прикол в том, что когда я делаю `npx prisma db reset` и запускаю сид то все прекрасно работает

```
root@80-78-241-34:~/wolf-game# npm run db:reset

> db:reset
> npx prisma migrate reset --schema src/core/prisma/schema.prisma

Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from src/core/prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "wolf" at "127.0.0.1:3306"

✔ Are you sure you want to reset your database? All data will be lost. … yes

Applying migration `20230823193102_devik`
Applying migration `20230823194102_dev`

Database reset successful

The following migration(s) have been applied:

migrations/
  └─ 20230823193102_devik/
    └─ migration.sql
  └─ 20230823194102_dev/
    └─ migration.sql

✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.15.0 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 468ms

Running seed command `ts-node src/core/prisma/seed.ts` ...
  The seed command has been executed.
```

Скрипты в package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "nest build",
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production && nest build && node dist/main",
        "db:seed": "npx prisma db seed",
        "db:push": "npx prisma db push --schema src/core/prisma/schema.prisma",
        "db:pull": "npx prisma db push --schema src/core/prisma/schema.prisma",
        "db:reset": "npx prisma migrate reset --schema src/core/prisma/schema.prisma",
        "db:gen": "npx prisma migrate dev --schema src/core/prisma/schema.prisma"
    },
    "prisma": {
        "seed": "ts-node src/core/prisma/seed.ts"
    },
```

Версия `Ubuntu-MySQL`

```
8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

При запуске проекта (`npm run start`) получаю ошибку

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `127.0.0.1`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `127.0.0.1`:`3306`.
    at r (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:108:2574)
    at async Proxy.onModuleInit (/root/wolf-game/dist/main.js:1950:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async callModuleInitHook (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
    at async NestApplication.callInitHook (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:224:13)
    at async NestApplication.init (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:98:9)
    at async NestApplication.listen (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:168:33)
    at async bootstrap (/root/wolf-game/dist/main.js:8632:5) {
  clientVersion: '4.15.0',
  errorCode: 'P1001'
}
```

Логи `pm2`

```
2023-08-28T06:40:46.852886Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-28T06:40:47.313100Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-28T06:40:47.697528Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-08-28T06:40:47.697616Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-08-28T06:40:47.741450Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-08-28T06:40:47.741861Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubun>2023-08-28T06:41:11.882824Z 8 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ca>2023-08-28T06:41:21.526797Z 9 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ca>2023-08-28T06:41:48.328392Z 10 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:42:03.902018Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:43:24.193984Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:45:19.652819Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:47:04.054263Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:47:46.794196Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:48:04.355022Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:48:38.627737Z 12 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:48:40.455639Z 13 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T06:52:08.963800Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
2023-08-28T06:52:10.178674Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-08-28T06:52:10.850985Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2162
2023-08-28T06:52:10.862550Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-28T06:52:11.328944Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-28T06:52:11.646676Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-08-28T06:52:11.646770Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-08-28T06:52:11.687259Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-08-28T06:52:11.687566Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubun>2023-08-28T06:52:25.606660Z 8 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ca>2023-08-28T06:52:34.044636Z 9 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ca>2023-08-28T07:03:24.788017Z 11 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:03:32.511641Z 12 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:09:54.549795Z 17 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:10:00.536958Z 18 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:11:36.550182Z 23 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:15:31.321139Z 36 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:15:44.789935Z 37 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:15:49.764717Z 38 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use c>2023-08-28T07:22:51.662649Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2873
2023-08-28T07:22:51.707681Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-28T07:22:53.553175Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-28T07:22:55.552254Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2023-08-28T07:22:57.637196Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2934
2023-08-28T07:22:57.673613Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-28T07:22:59.418652Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-28T07:23:27.939303Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2023-08-28T07:23:29.696671Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2989
2023-08-28T07:23:29.723877Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-28T07:23:32.446079Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-28T07:23:35.736014Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 3027
```

Перед запуском `npm run start` статус `mysql`

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-08-28 11:27:13 MSK; 5min ago
    Process: 10615 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 10631 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 39 (limit: 1138)
     Memory: 391.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─10631 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 28 11:27:11 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 28 11:27:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

После запуска `npm run start` статус `mysql`

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2023-08-28 11:14:13 MSK; 1min 57s ago
    Process: 10141 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 10151 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 10151 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"

Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 172.
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 28 11:14:13 80-78-241-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Уже пробовал вместо `127.0.0.1` ставить `localhost`, результат тот же.

Прошу заметить, что **проект запускается**, однако при первом же апдейте пользователя выходит код 0 и крашит `MySQL`, при этом в `pm2` до сих пор статус `online`

```
0|wolf     | > start
0|wolf     | > cross-env NODE_ENV=production && nest build && node dist/main
0|wolf     |
0|wolf     | webpack 5.71.0 compiled successfully in 292251 ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application... +351ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PrismaModule dependencies initialized +62ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TelegrafModule dependencies initialized +1ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TranslateModule dependencies initialized +2ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CoreModule dependencies initialized +0ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CommandModule dependencies initialized +1ms
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:41 AM     LOG [I18nService] Checking translation changes
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:42 AM     LOG [I18nService] No changes detected
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9719  - 08/28/2023, 11:10:42 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +65ms

0|wolf  | Unhandled error while processing {
0|wolf  |   update_id: 698018945,
0|wolf  |   message: {
0|wolf  |     message_id: 5992,
0|wolf  |     from: {
0|wolf  |       id: 915886906,
0|wolf  |       is_bot: false,
0|wolf  |       first_name: 'максон',
0|wolf  |       username: 'impuLssse911',
0|wolf  |       language_code: 'en',
0|wolf  |       is_premium: true
0|wolf  |     },
0|wolf  |     chat: {
0|wolf  |       id: 915886906,
0|wolf  |       first_name: 'максон',
0|wolf  |       username: 'impuLssse911',
0|wolf  |       type: 'private'
0|wolf  |     },
0|wolf  |     date: 1693210315,
0|wolf  |     text: '/mywolfy',
0|wolf  |     entities: [ [Object] ]
0|wolf  |   }
0|wolf  | }
0|wolf  | node:internal/process/promises:288
0|wolf  |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
0|wolf  |             ^
0|wolf  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
0|wolf  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
0|wolf  |   errno: -111,
0|wolf  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|wolf  |   syscall: 'connect',
0|wolf  |   address: '::1',
0|wolf  |   port: 3306,
0|wolf  |   fatal: true
0|wolf  | }
0|wolf  | Node.js v18.17.1
PM2     | App [wolf:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2     | App [wolf:0] starting in -fork mode-
```

Вот еще пример этой ошибки

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`
0|wolf     |
0|wolf     | Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`3306`.
0|wolf     |     at r (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:108:2574)
0|wolf     |     at async Proxy.onModuleInit (/root/wolf-game/dist/main.js:1950:9)
0|wolf     |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
0|wolf     |     at async callModuleInitHook (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
0|wolf     |     at async NestApplication.callInitHook (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:224:13)
0|wolf     |     at async NestApplication.init (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:98:9)
0|wolf     |     at async NestApplication.listen (/root/wolf-game/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:168:33)
0|wolf     |     at async bootstrap (/root/wolf-game/dist/main.js:8632:5) {
0|wolf     |   clientVersion: '4.15.0',
0|wolf     |   errorCode: 'P1001'
0|wolf     | }
0|wolf     |
0|wolf     | Node.js v18.17.1
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | RpcExitError: Process 153416 exited [SIGKILL].
0|wolf     | Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
0|wolf     | If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript.
0|wolf     | [Nest] 7537  - 08/28/2023, 10:56:39 AM   ERROR [CONFIG] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
0|wolf     | Unhandled error while processing {
0|wolf     |   update_id: 698018909,
0|wolf     |   message: {
0|wolf     |     message_id: 6510650,
0|wolf     |     from: {
0|wolf     |       id: 707589096,
0|wolf     |       is_bot: false,
0|wolf     |       first_name: 'baby shark',
0|wolf     |       username: 'kicking_up_daisies',
0|wolf     |       language_code: 'ru'
0|wolf     |     },
0|wolf     |     chat: {
0|wolf     |       id: -1001362508472,
0|wolf     |       title: 'Black Werewolves Rage',
0|wolf     |       type: 'supergroup'
0|wolf     |     },
0|wolf     |     date: 1693209402,
0|wolf     |     message_thread_id: 6510649,
0|wolf     |     reply_to_message: {
0|wolf     |       message_id: 6510649,
0|wolf     |       from: [Object],
0|wolf     |       chat: [Object],
0|wolf     |       date: 1693208564,
0|wolf     |       text: 'Сиси на стол'
0|wolf     |     },
0|wolf     |     text: 'итак на столе лежат'
0|wolf     |   }
0|wolf     | }
0|wolf     | node:internal/process/promises:288
0|wolf     |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
0|wolf     |             ^
0|wolf     |
0|wolf     | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
0|wolf     |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
0|wolf     |   errno: -111,
0|wolf     |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|wolf     |   syscall: 'connect',
0|wolf     |   address: '::1',
0|wolf     |   port: 3306,
0|wolf     |   fatal: true
0|wolf     | }
0|wolf     |
0|wolf     | Node.js v18.17.1
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | Killed
0|wolf     | RpcExitError: Process 8824 exited [SIGKILL].
0|wolf     | Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
0|wolf     | If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript.
0|wolf     | [Nest] 9279  - 08/28/2023, 11:05:20 AM   ERROR [CONFIG] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
0|wolf     | Unhandled error while processing {
0|wolf     |   update_id: 698018937,
0|wolf     |   message: {
0|wolf     |     message_id: 6510679,
0|wolf     |     from: {
0|wolf     |       id: 707589096,
0|wolf     |       is_bot: false,
0|wolf     |       first_name: 'baby shark',
0|wolf     |       username: 'kicking_up_daisies',
0|wolf     |       language_code: 'ru'
0|wolf     |     },
0|wolf     |     chat: {
0|wolf     |       id: -1001362508472,
0|wolf     |       title: 'Black Werewolves Rage',
0|wolf     |       type: 'supergroup'
0|wolf     |     },
0|wolf     |     date: 1693209938,
0|wolf     |     text: 'я не увидела связи'
0|wolf     |   }
0|wolf     | }
0|wolf     | node:internal/process/promises:288
0|wolf     |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
0|wolf     |             ^
0|wolf     |
0|wolf     | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
0|wolf     |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
0|wolf     |   errno: -111,
0|wolf     |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|wolf     |   syscall: 'connect',
0|wolf     |   address: '::1',
0|wolf     |   port: 3306,
0|wolf     |   fatal: true
0|wolf     | }
```

Файл `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048
long_query_time=512
```

Файл `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
# pid-file      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port          = 3306
# datadir       = /var/lib/mysql

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address     = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
```

Comment: [Почему не стоит добавлять данные в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)